# How did google get the outline for postcodes on maps?

Tags: google-maps, location, polygon

For example: http://g.co/maps/2dpkj has the outline around the postcode area. I understand this is unavailable through the API , but where else can I get this data, eg in a KML format.

**This is for UK Data**

Comment: to clarify your question:  There are no "boundaries" for a Postal Unit(post code)..LE14 2EF, However, there are boundaries for the Postal Sector(LE14 2), Postal District(LE14), and Postal Area(LE).   sounds like what you may want is boundaries for postal sectors..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Most likely* Google have a licensing agreement with Ordnance Survey that allows them to use the [Code Points with Polygons](http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/oswebsite/products/code-point-polygons/index.html) data - I imagine they've then done some processing of the data to generate a KML file. Depending on your GIS skills and your ability to read the source file (ESRI/MapInfo), you should be able to do the same.

An alternative is to use the [Code Point](http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/oswebsite/products/code-point-open/index.html) dataset, which has the virtue of being free and is supplied as a CSV file, however you'll need to re-process it to re-generate the polygons. There's a project on Google Code that I think will help you with this, [geocoordconversion](http://code.google.com/p/geocoordconversion/). Adrian Hills has a blog [here](http://www.adathedev.co.uk/2011/01/gb-post-code-geographic-data-load-to.html) on using the DLL with the Code Points dataset.

Comment: "An alternative is to use the Code Point dataset" - I already use this to find the postcode upon the map, however this data does not have bounds I don't believe?

Comment: If there is lack of a more appropriate/sufficient answer within 7 days I will mark this as answer, as it certainly links to a location to obtain the polygons

Comment: @rickyduck We've been playing with this recently and deriving the polygons from the Code Points dataset by placing each boundary halfway between the individual points. It's by no means a perfect method, but the resulting polygons are surprisingly close to the actual boundaries.

Comment: hmm, that makes sense. The biggest predicament is if a postcode contains 20 properties, then the next one contains 5, but you set it to half way between, its going to be way off? And then if you work it out from no. of addresses, you have the problem of flats containing (eg) 30 properties despite being one building...

Comment: @rickyduck For our purposes we only go down to sector-level, mapping individual units isn't a problem we face...

Comment: that makes you the lucky one ;)

Comment: New link https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-government/products/code-point-polygons

Answer (score 5):

Is this what you're after?

https://www.google.com/fusiontables/data?docid=1jgWYtlqGSPzlIa-is8wl1cZkVIWEm_89rWUwqFU#rows:id=1

There are polygons for each postcode area, which was certainly good enough for my application.

Comment: Hi Phil, unfortunately that is for outcode, while I need the full postcode (ie LE14 2EF)

Comment: Ah, in that case you're going to have to pay for the data then, as PhilPursglove has alluded to. I have been contemplating writing an algorithm to divide the country up and creating my own boundary data, but it's just too much hard work!

Answer (score 3):

Even if I don't know exactly where they got it from I would assume from the [TIGER Data](http://www.census.gov/geo/www/tiger/).

OK, so what TIGER is for the US is [INSPIRE](http://inspire.jrc.ec.europa.eu/) for Europe. INSPIRE claims all European countries to publish their spatial data. I think this directive is already in charge so you should checkout their portal and see if you find what you are looking for.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, forgot to specify this is UK Data! Upvote anyways

Comment: TIGER data looks like it's for the US, I suspect from the sample URL the OP is talking about the UK...

Comment: however the links were UK examples (as @PhilPursglove gathered)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very useful [API](https://www.boundaries-io.com) to do this now, create complex geo spatial queries(multiple postal districts,etc..)

UK Postal Code(ex. ZE1 0AE) ,Sector, District, City, and Wards Boundaries
returns GeoJson, so you can integrate easily in google maps!

Simple monthly subscription model..
quick REST call :

```
 /boundary/uk?postal-sector=ab16 9&postal-unit=ab16 9uw
```

Image of the results in GooleMap:
[image]

Comment: Hey Jeryl, you never actually posted the link?

Comment: www.boundaries-io.com