# How to display states of Mexico or other countries like USA

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Any idea how or if the states of Mexico or other countries ie Chile can be displayed with the states borders drawn and the names of the states displayed with Google Maps.?
USA maps have each state displayed as default.

Do I need to do some sort of overlay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The state outlines are available in the Natural Earth Data set in FusionTables also and can be overlaid using a FusionTablesLayer:

[Mexico](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_FusionTables_query_sidebarF_local.html?country=Mexico)

[Chile](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_FusionTables_query_sidebarF_local.html?country=Chile)

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the outlines from a third party, and then draw them as an overlay.

I believe one source you can use for the US is **[TIGER](http://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger.html)**.

*from this question: **[How did google get the outline for postcodes on maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886500/how-did-google-get-the-outline-for-postcodes-on-maps)**

EDIT: I also read that you can use the [OpenStreetMap API](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) to get the outlines.